# Prevent sharing with UIActivityViewController to certain apps

Tags: ios, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

From my iOS-App I would like to disable sharing to Apps like Tumblr or Instapaper. My instance of UIActivityViewController has the property `excludedActivityTypes`, but what exactly do I put into this array?

For example, when Tumblr-sharing succeeds, the activity name, taken from `completionWithItemsHandler` is `com.tumblr.tumblr.Share-With-Tumblr`. But adding this string to `excludedActivityTypes` doesn't remove Tumblr from the list of choices.

Comment: I think the same problem is here : http://johnszumski.com/blog/excluding-third-party-apps-from-ios-8-share-sheet

Comment: I also see this problem, is there any solution?

Comment: I haven't checked but I assume only Apple can solve this problem (cleanly). See johnszumski.com link above.